# Using read_csv with path to a file (readr's package)

Tags: r

I face a difficulty in trying to read a csv file with `read_csv` function from `readr` package using file's path.

My file ("test.csv") is located in the 'data' folder.
Data folder is located at the root of my project (working directory)

```
wd <- getwd()
data_path <- "data"
file.exists(file.path(wd, data_path, "test.csv")) # Returns TRUE
library(readr)

data.1 <- read_csv(file = file.path(wd, data_path, "test.csv")) # Does not work
```

The log provides me with the following error:

> Error in withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning")) : 
>         argument "x" is missing, with no default

However it works perfectly with the standard `read.csv` function

```
data.1 <- read.csv("data/mockup_data_v1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") # OK
```

Could you please let me know how to proceed to use `read_csv` from `readr` package with file path as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already set your working directory, you should be able to just read the file with:

```
data.1 <- read_csv("data/test.csv")
```

Because R looks in your working directory by default, you are in effect asking R to look in:

```
working directory/working directory/data/test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add paste and you should be good to go

```
library(readr)

wd <- getwd()
data_path <- "data"

data.1 <- read_csv(paste(wd, data_path, "test.csv"))
```